# How to allow a manual build step only in main branch for GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

My CI/CD pipeline contains a manual build task. Is there a way to only allow this manual step in a specific branch?

I tried:

```yaml
deploy-macos:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
          when: manual
```

But that fails with the following error:

```
jobs:deploy-macos:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `'` in your if:

```
deploy-macos:
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
          when: manual
```